# What's the best approach to implement User Location Tracker in Android nowadays

Tags: android, kotlin, geolocation, location, fusedlocationproviderclient

I know and I have read some articles that give us some tutorial about how to do this, but when I want to implement one of the approach they have given, I usually got null or errors with `FusedLocationProviderClient` It usually happened when I turned off the GPS and turned It back on. And when I opened the Google Maps and back into my app, the `FusedLocationProviderClient` back to normal and gives actual longitude and latitude. Any idea or help for how can I handle this kind of bug?

Comment: Can you share what you have done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nah nevermind, I solved it by replacing fusedLocation.lastLocation() with fusedLocation.currentLocation(). My bad for following tutorial that uses lastLocation

Answer (score 0):

First do null check on `FusedLocationProviderClient` and then procced the steps you want to perform.